# How to calculate database device size in Sybase (SAP ASE 16)

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, stored-procedures, sap-ase

I am trying to calculate database device size (total mb in use, total reserved mb, and remaining mb as a %) through Sybase (SAP ASE 16) MDA/system tables.  Currently, I can successfully calculate total mb in use (I have verified through sp_displaydevice) but I cannot figure out total mb allocated PER each database device.

My Query:

```
select
    logical_name = d.name,
    physical_name = d.phyname,
    d.vdevno as vdevno,
    size = (d.high - d.low + 1) * 2.0 / 1024.0,
    reserved = isnull(sum(u.size) * 2.0 / 1024.0, 0),
    left = isnull(sum(u.size) * 2.0 / 1024.0, 0) - (d.high - d.low + 1) * 2.0 / 1024.0
from
    master.dbo.sysdevices d,
    master.dbo.sysusages u
where
    d.status & 2 = 2
    and u.vstart / power(2, 24) = * d.low / power(2, 24)
group by
    substring(d.name, 1, 12),
    substring(d.phyname, 1, 17),
    d.low / power(2, 24),
    (d.high - d.low + 1) * 2 / 1024.0
order by
    vdevno
```

That's a modified version of this: http://www.rocket99.com/techref/sybase8707.html

Am I understanding devices wrong?  For example, do all databases share disk space on a given sybase instance?  Which is why their 'reserved_mb' all return the same value?  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Side note: The result of this query will be inserted into a table for further manipulation.

Comment: a few issues ... **1)** you should update the question with the 'wrong' results generated plus the correct/expected results, **2)** ASE pagesize is one of 2048, 4096, 8192 or 16384 but your query appears to be hardcoded for 2048 which will cause your query to generate wrong results in an ASE with a pagesize of 4096/8192/16384 - consider using `@@maxpagesize`, **3)** while ASE will allow non-standard `group by` clauses (ie, mismatch between `group by` clauses and non-aggregate `select` clauses), the results of your query will likely be wrong ...

Comment: **4)** starting with ASE 15 (and carried over into ASE 16), the `sysdevices <--> sysusages` relationship is based on the `vdevno` columns; I would suggest you take a look at the source code for `sp_helpdevice` - this system proc has all the queries you'll need to roll your own code to display device space stats